# SKView warning logs

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, swiftui, uiviewrepresentable

When running my SwiftUI & SpriteKit app, I get the following messages in the logs:

> 2019-11-18 21:58:57.631912+0000 PixelBattles[2812:1215803]
>
> SKView: ignoreRenderSyncInLayoutSubviews is NO. Call _renderSynchronouslyForTime without handler

What am I doing wrong to receive this log, and should I worry about it? Could it be a bug?

Could it be that SwiftUI cannot figure out how to do the layout for an `SKView`?

### Major edit:

<sup>If you need code, you can see it in the previous edits. Below I state why I don't think it is any longer relevant.</sup>

I have sent Apple some feedback (`FB7456217`). I have removed the code, as I no longer suspect it is an issue to do with my code. I created a blank game project, no SwiftUI, and still got the same warning log instantly.

So even with the default project template, the log still appeared for device and simulator. I will update on this issue if I get a useful response.

---

I still haven't heard anything back - has anyone got any new information since when I posted this over half a month ago? I still have these warnings!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is Apple's response to this issue:

> Hi! You don't really need to fix that. That's a log message that was
> left by mistake in SpriteKit framework. It was removed and will no
> longer appear in the future SpriteKit versions. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you! They never got back to me, and it was not marked as duplicate either. I have now closed the issue.

Answer (score 3):

just figured this out for myself.

In your code change

`if let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")`

to

`if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene")`

Answer (score 3):

I believe you'll also get this warning if you have UIKit subviews of the SKView.

Comment: Is it a problem to use UIKit inside of an SKView or can the warning be ignored?

Comment: Doesn’t _seem_ to cause any issues, but who knows.