# How do I resolve this error: "SKView: ignoreRenderSyncInLayoutSubviews is NO"?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm getting the following error a lot:

> SKView: ignoreRenderSyncInLayoutSubviews is NO. Call _renderSynchronouslyForTime without handler

I have 4 different game states in my game and one of them is a UI, but this error pops up and it skips over that game state. Can you please help? I am using Xcode 11.4.1 and the phone I'm using is on iOS 13.4.1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SKView warning logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58923683/skview-warning-logs)

Comment: I have let scene = GameScene(fileNamed: "GameScene") and it is giving me that error